# Commits do not show up on Gitlab

Tags: git, svn, repository, gitlab, unreal-engine4

I have a question about the free version of GitLab.
We have chosen Gitlab because we are making a game in UnrealEngine, so the repository is over 8GB.
In my team there is problem with this git repository, because the commits aren't showing up on the server. They are presented when we are using *gitk* but on server the commits are messed up. 
This seems to happen on and off.

My questions:

1. Is there any way to repair this bug?
2. If there is any repository, regardless the technology (SVN,GIT, or whatever) that can handle 5GB or more space, for free as a student project?

Comment: so the repository is over 8GB???? You should expect problems, 2Gb is HUGE so 8 Is .....

Comment: Its normal for a game especially in Unreal Engine

Comment: Might be but dont store big binary in the repo. use https://git-lfs.github.com/

Comment: Git has problems handling such a big repo since on push/pull it has to re-pack the content and writing and handling 8GB is a problem. Try to "get rid" of your binary files to clear room in your repo

Answer (score 2):

> > so the repository is over 8GB ????
>
> https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota/

#### File and repository size limitations (from github)

> We recommend repositories be kept under 1GB each. This limit is easy to stay within if large files are kept out of the repository. If your repository exceeds 1GB, you might receive a polite email from GitHub Support requesting that you reduce the size of the repository to bring it back down.
>
> In addition, we place a strict limit of files exceeding 100 MB in size. For more information, see "Working with large files."

---

> If there is any repository, regardless the technology (SVN,GIT, or whatever) that can handle 5GB or more space, for free as a student project?

You can use `github` with the LFS - https://git-lfs.github.com/

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to repair this bug?

*This is not a bug. It is a limitation of Git / Gitlab / GitHub.*

> If there is any repository, regardless the technology (SVN,GIT, or
>   whatever) that can handle 5GB or more space, for free as a student
>   project?

*Deploy your own server and take control over your data.* The official Unreal Engine documentation suggests using Subversion or Perforce:

- [Subversion: VisualSVN Server guide](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Basics/SourceControl/SVN/index.html)
- [Perforce guide](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Basics/SourceControl/Perforce/index.html)

First of all, deploy your own version-control server if you are going to use version-control in gamedev and are going to store assets assets in the same repository with your source core. The best choice would be to deploy the server on your LAN. If it is not possible or your team is distributed, choose Amazon or Azure hosting which is closest to you.

Think twice when choosing Git as version control for you gamedev project. Git is not the best choice if you use Unreal Engine and your game assets are heavy. Git is a content tracker for source code and does not really support versioning large binaries and huge repositories by design (however, there are some extensions like `git-lfs` but they don't really make any real difference in case of large number game assets or other binaries).

Answer (score -1):

Not sure exactly what you are running into, but we often debug problems when pushing/cloning large files from/to GitLab. Often if you are push/pulling over http it is going to timeout after around a minute. In the lastest GitLab most of the timeouts are longer/unlimited, if data is being transferred, but building the pack file often takes so long for the large files, that even the newest GitLab times out on http. Your best bet is to use ssh only for large files.

If you are actually wanting to diff and do code review on the binaries, and you are having trouble using git to do it, you will likely want to try Perforce's Helix Version Engine. It's free for up to 20 users, and has a activity and merge request webserver application called Helix Swarm: https://www.perforce.com/collaboration (that you have to setup separately).